# Using the slot setText(const QString &text)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, slot

I want to use the slot `setText(const QString &text)`

```
     QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), ui->textEdit, SLOT(setText(const QString &text)));
```

Where can i put the text to display in my `QTextEdit`?

I have a `QTreeWidget` and i want to display the `currentitem()`.

Comment: Please, compare the signatures of [`QTreeWidget::itemSelectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) and [`QTextEdit::setText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText) - they are not matching. Hence, it is not that simple. You have to write a function (or lambda) which retrieves the text of current item from tree widget to pass it to the `QTextEdit`.

Comment: how can i do this ? i have to write new signal ? thanks

Comment: Since Qt5, any matching function/member function can be used as slot. Due to this, one option is to use a lambda as adapter between sender and receiver (as shown in Romha's answer). It is called "adapter" as it adapts a non-matching slot function signature to that requied by the signal. You don't need a new signal nor a new slot - you just wrap your existing slot in a lambda which transforms (or enriches) the necessary information for your slot. Btw. you are using Qt5? Qt4 did not yet provide these features.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the parameter value when you call your slot. If you use Qt5, you can use lambda:

```
connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::itemSelectionChanged,
[=] { ui->textEdit->setText(ui->treeWidget->currentItem()->text(); });
```

Comment: its says expected expression , what does that mean ?